# how do you add a right button to a uinavigationcontrol

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

How can I add a button to a `UINavigationControl` that I added to a `ViewController`? (The project isn't `UINavigationControler` based.)

Here's the code I've added to my `viewDidLoad` method:

```
navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
navigation.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748);
navigation.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
navigation.navigationBar.alpha = 1.0f;
navigation.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancel)];          
[navigation.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:cancelButton animated:YES];
[cancelButton release];

[self.view addSubview:navigation.view];

[self pushPresentationList];
```

Can someone help me fix lines 7-9 please?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Button" 
    style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:nil action:nil];
UINavigationItem *item = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Awesome"];
item.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
item.hidesBackButton = YES;
[navigationBar pushNavigationItem:item animated:NO];
```

Comment: ^ This crashes my application.
I also get a warning "navigation may not respond to pushNavigationItem".

Comment: I think it should be [navigation.navigationBar pushNavigationItem:item animated:NO];

Answer (score 0):

Do you need an UINavigationController? Why not just use a simple UINavigationBar. Here is some sample code:

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:
                              CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, 49.0f)];
[self.view addSubview:navBar];
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel"
      style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancel)];
UINavigationItem *rightBarButtonItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];

[rightBarButtonItem setRightBarButtonItem:cancelButton];

[navBar pushNavigationItem:rightBarButtonItem animated:NO];
```